# Save remainder in variable

Tags: c#

I would like how i save the remainder of an sum in an variable.

**EXAMPLE** : calculate seconds to hours:

**USER-INPUT**: `524000` (seconds)

**ANSWER**:    `14H 33M 20S`

I would do something like this:

```
console.writeline("Enter seconds")
int seconds = int.parse(console.readline());
int hours = seconds / 3600;
console.writeline("Seconds calculated in hours = {0}",hours);
```

The remainder is 2000 seconds divided by 60 = 33 and an remainder of 20.
But how can i save this remainder in an another variable?

Comment: Use modulo (http://www.dotnetperls.com/modulo), like: seconds % 3600.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Modulo Operator (%) but to this question wouldn't it be easier to use TimeSpan?

```
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5400);
```

And then ofcourse show the answer. *(Hint: String.Format())*

Comment: My main goal isn't to do it the most efficient way, but exercise. But thank you for you're answer tried both and it worked.

Comment: @user2022298 Ahh, well I provided an answer to the original question too, but showed the most efficient way aswell, so I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use iVisions implementation, but if you have to calculate the remainder of other values use modulo

```
 int remainder = seconds % 3600
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/modulo

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it like this:

```
2000 / 60 = 33  ==> (2000 - (33*60) = 20)
```

Or use the [modulo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0w4e0fzs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) operator:

```
2000 % 60 = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` and the `%` operator, you can use [`Math.DivRem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.divrem.aspx) method:

```
int hours = Math.DivRem(seconds, 3600, out seconds);
int minutes = Math.DivRem(seconds, 60, out seconds);
```